# Slider contents shifting on windows resize

Tags: javascript, css

Running into an issue where the width of my slide elements shift when the browser window is resized. Refreshing the page causes the slide width to be calculated correctly on reload. I'm really not sure what's causing the values to change on window resize. They kind of just run off the stage a bit and then get cut off by the overflow:hidden.

```js
const slidesContainer = document.getElementById("slides-container");
const slide = document.querySelector(".slide");
const prevButton = document.getElementById("slide-arrow-prev");
const nextButton = document.getElementById("slide-arrow-next");

nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const slideWidth = slide.clientWidth;
  slidesContainer.scrollLeft += slideWidth;
});

prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const slideWidth = slide.clientWidth;
  slidesContainer.scrollLeft -= slideWidth;
});
```

```css
.slider-wrapper {
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 100ms;
}

.slide-arrow:hover,
.slide-arrow:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

#slide-arrow-prev {
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 0 2rem 2rem 0;
}

#slide-arrow-next {
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: unset!important;
    flex: 4 0 25%;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider-wrapper">
  <button class="slide-arrow" id="slide-arrow-prev">
    &#8249;
  </button>
  <button class="slide-arrow" id="slide-arrow-next">
    &#8250;
  </button>
  <ul class="slides-container" id="slides-container">
    <li class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
</li>
    <li class="slide">Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

</li>
    <li class="slide">Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.

</li>
    <li class="slide">Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. 
</li>    
    <li class="slide">Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</li>    
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a function to realign the slide if the window size changed

```
function reportWindowSize() {
   const slideWidth = slide.clientWidth;
   slidesContainer.scrollLeft = slideWidth;
}
window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
```